# Kafka vs. MongoDB for time series data

Tags: mongodb, logging, apache-kafka, time-series

I'm contemplating on whether to use MongoDB or Kafka for a time series dataset.

At first sight obviously it makes sense to use Kafka since that's what it's built for. But I would also like some flexibility in querying, etc.

Which brought me to question: "Why not just use MongoDB to store the timestamped data and index them by timestamp?"

Naively thinking, this feels like it has the similar benefit of Kafka (in that it's indexed by time offset) but has more flexibility. But then again, I'm sure there are plenty of reasons why people use Kafka instead of MongoDB for this type of use case.

Could someone explain some of the reasons why one may want to use Kafka instead of MongoDB in this case?

Comment: ermmm, [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) as a time series data storage? And it's built for it? It seems your view of the system lacks an essential  component behind the broker - the time-series database itself.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could answer and explain instead of calling me an idiot. I asked the question exactly because I have very shallow understanding of the system and would like to learn. Also it's not like I'm asking even without trying. I AM running a massive kafka infra for my own project so i'm not completely clueless, I do understand how it works but just want to learn what i'm missing. Just like how most early MongoDB users misunderstood how MongoDB should be used, I'm sure there are people out there like me who are wondering.

Comment: It's hard to answer. One is a message broker, another is a database. It's like apples vs running. Can you answer what is better?

Comment: Mongo isn't even a TSDB... Perhaps you want TimescaleDB, OpenTsdb, or Kairos? Also Kafka isn't indexed by time, only by offsets within a partition

Comment: Okay, I own an apology. Indeed Kafka can be used as a database. Never thought about it as such and learned something new today. Search and and grouping seems a bit complicated, but I assume it's not a problem. After all some use even elastic search as a time series storage. Mongo is not worse - it's general purpose db and can store any data, including time series. The question is in efficiency. Purpose-built tsdb will win any of them just because they were designed for that from the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to take this question as that you're trying to collect metrics over time

Yes, Kafka topics have configurable time retentions, and I doubt you're using topic compaction because your messages would likely be in the form of `(time, value)`, so the time could not be repeated anyway.

Kafka also provides stream processing libraries so that you can find out averages, min/max, outliers&anamolies, top K, etc. values over windows of time.

However, while processing all that data is great and useful, your consumers would be stuck doing linear scans of this data, not easily able to query slices of it for any given time range. And that's where time indexes (not just a start index, but also an end) would help.

So, sure you can use Kafka to create a backlog of queued metrics and process/filter them over time, but I would suggest consuming that data into a proper database because I assume you'll want to be able to query it easier and potentially create some visualizations over that data.

With that architecture, you could have your highly available Kafka cluster holding onto data for some amount of time, while your downstream systems don't necessarily have to be online all the time in order to receive events. But once they are, they'd consume from the last available offset and pickup where they were before

Comment: I know this is an old question, but you CAN do arbitrary, optimized queries now of Kafka streams using https://ksqldb.io/.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "arbitrary" when it requires a defined schema and only supports certain serialization types. It's also not really a good use case to replace a TSDB

Comment: Time series seems EXACTLY the use case for ksqlDB. I don't understand why you'd say that.

Comment: I said it doesn't replace a TSDB (Druid, Prometheus, Influx, etc), not that it cannot be used to operate on time-series data

Comment: I think you're not getting that ksqlDB is a new Kafka feature/add-on, and that ksqlDB is a full TSDB with arbitrary optimized SQL queries possible.

Comment: But it's not actually a database, and has no proper indicies or persistent storage on its own. It's a query engine / stream processor, first and foremost

Comment: Seriously. Look up "ksqlDB". It won't let me paste a link. "ksqlDB is a database that's purpose-built for stream processing applications." It creates materialized views of the data, which IS persistent storage. And whatever queries that are programmed are updated in real time. It's a cool system.

Comment: @Some Marketing department can write whatever they want to. I use ksql at work already. Still doesn't change my mind that a TSDB works better for the original question

Answer (score 2):

Like the answers in the comments above - neither Kafka nor MongoDB are well suited as a time-series DB with flexible query capabilities, for the reasons that @Alex Blex explained well.

Depending on the requirements for processing speed vs. query flexibility vs. data size, I would do the following choices:

1. Cassandra [best processing speed, best/good data size limits, worst query flexibility]
2. TimescaleDB on top of PostgresDB [good processing speed, good/OK data size limits, good query flexibility]
3. ElasticSearch [good processing speed, worst data size limits, best query flexibility + visualization]

P.S. by "processing" here I mean both ingestion, partitioning and roll-ups where needed
P.P.S. I picked those options that are most widely used now, in my opinion, but there are dozens and dozens of other options and combinations, and many more selection criteria to use  - would be interested to hear about other engineers' experiences!

Comment: Note: Kafka can be used to funnel data *into* these systems

Comment: the question was about whether Kafka can be used as a time-series DB. And the answer to that is "no" as many pointed out. Kafka can surely be used for many other cases - just not as a DB in a traditional sense - for storing and querying data

Comment: You can store and query data from a RocksDB instance built by Kafka Streams, though, so I feel like you're only taking the perspective of the broker